# Passing a file input HTML to php with AJAX JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want pass a file of one form to a php with AJAX JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div class="imagen bloque">
   <div class="imagen-prev-texto">Vista previa</div>
   <div class="imagen-prev"><img src="img/stop" alt="" width="200px" height="200px"></div>
   <form id="form">
      <input type="file" id="fileselectInput"><br>
      <button type="button" onclick="previewIMG()"> Submit </button>
   </form>
</div>
```

PHP subir_img_producto:

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Code Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>"; /
}
  else
{
if (file_exists("tmp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exist in the server. "; 
  }
else
  {
  $rutafinal ="tmp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$rutafinal);
  echo $rutafinal;
  //echo "Stored in: " . "tmp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
  }
}
  }
else
  {
     echo "no valid file";
  }
```

I try this with JavaScript, but no works

```
function previewIMG() {
    var formData = new FormData($("#form"));
    alert(formData);
    var url ="subir_img_producto.php";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", formData.length);
    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    http.send(formData);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('cuadroIMG').src=http.responseText;
        }
    }
    }
```

I used a php with a basic form in HTML and it worked perfectly, so the PHP is fine.

I exeute all of this in apache server, XAMPP.

I hope I've put everything you need to help me, I'm not averse been using jQuery but I have no knowledge of jQuery, but will use if necessary.

Comment: try to var_dump your $_POST and your $_FILES

Comment: i only cant var_dump me files, i no have POST in mi php. Result for example with image named "winter": `array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "winter" [1]=> string(3) "jpg" }`

Comment: btw you could check your file endings and file size in the users browser already. For example: var ul_file = $(this).val(); var extension = ul_file.substr((ul_file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)); var accepted_file_endings = ["ogg", "ogv", "avi", "mpeg", "mpg", "mov", "wmv", "flv", "mp4"]; extension = extension.toLowerCase(); if ($.inArray(extension, accepted_file_endings) !== -1) { // start upload ... } - you can also get the file size with selecting the file input and add ".size" :)

Comment: I know, but do not understand how this can solve my problem, PHP goes well, the mistake is to pass the FORM in JavaScript with AJAX, sorry if i don't understand you

Comment: ok. that seems correct. I copied your code and tried it in my xampp. I noticed that you used "var formData = new FormData($("#form"));" - The $ is a jQuery selector. Import the jQuery library and try it again please!

Comment: i write in mi "head" tag this --> `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` and still no works

Comment: found the error. Check my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $("#fileselectInput")[0].files[0];
formData.append("file", file);
```

This is the correct use of formdata. But now you have fix the paths. var_dump($_FILES), var_dump($_POST) and use not alert, use console.log(formData) and debug this. When you do it correct it will work :)

And of course you have to append the filename again, should work with formData.append("name", file.name);

EDIT:
PHP:

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{

if (file_exists("tmp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exist in the server. "; 
  }
else
  {
  $rutafinal ="tmp/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$rutafinal);
  echo $rutafinal;

  }

  }
else
  {
     echo "no valid file";
  }
```

JS:

```
function previewIMG() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = $("#fileselectInput")[0].files[0];

    formData.append("file", file);
    console.log(formData);
    var url ="subir_img_producto.php";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", url, true);        
    http.send(formData);

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

                    alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I go edit the JS with you code, but i don't know how " fix the paths. var_dump($_FILES), var_dump($_POST) " and And do not I know what you mean, "And of course You have to append the filename again, Should not work with formData.append (" name ", file.name);" sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Check out the updated answer. But you really have to learn how to debug with var_dump and console.log :P